# Get Asset Image File Name

Tags: templating, assets

I'm trying to get the actual file name of each images when looping through the image assets folder, which looks like:

```
{% for image in craft.assets.kind('image').folderId('1').order('filename') %}
    <li><a href="#"><img src="{{ image.getUrl() }}" alt="{{ image.title }}"></a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I need to be able to include the filename of the image as a data attribute in the `<a>` tag. I tried all sorts of variations of {{ image.fileName }} but have had no luck. Can't find a solution searching here. Does anyone know how? Better yet - is there a documentation somewhere showing all the available twig attributes for assets/images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`image.filename` should work unless I'm missing something. Note that it is case-sensitive.

The documentation on `AssetFileModel` can be found here:
http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/assetfilemodel

Comment: Of course the one variation I did not try was all lowercase. Sigh. That worked. Thanks for answering!

Comment: It's always that way for me. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes. Happy to help!